# How can I install VS 2008 team suite sp1 without the original installation media (vs_Setup.msi)?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, tfs, visual-studio-2008-sp1

I am trying to re-install VS2008 SP1.  Why?

I installed the [VS2008 Forward Compatibility Update (KB974558)](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=CF13EA45-D17B-4EDC-8E6C-6C5B208EC54D&displaylang=en), in order to be able to access TFS 2010 from VS2008. Everything went fine; there were no error messages.  When I start VS2008 and click Help..About, I can see that KB794558 is installed.

But even though the FCU is installed, I still cannot add a TFS 2010 server path into Visual Studio 2008, without getting the error [TF30335](http://www.bing.com/search?q=tf30335).  The server in question is a codeplex server; I understand that codeplex upgraded to TFS 2010 in July.

Some websites have suggested re-installing VS2008 SP1 in order to correct this TF30335 error. But when I try doing *that*, the install asks for the original installation media for VS 2008 Team Suite (vs_setup.msi), which I no longer have.

Other websites, like [this one](http://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2009/06/10/connecting-visual-studio-2008-team-explorer-to-team-foundation-server-2010/), suggest manually tweaking the registry to add a TFS 2010 URL.  When I restart VS2008 after doing this, I get the TF253022 error, which says, **You must update your client with the Forward Compatibility Update.**  As I said, I've already installed that.

1. Is there a way to (re-)install VS2008 sp1 without access to the original VS2008 installation media?
2. Failing that, is there a way to avoid the TF30335 error, after installing the FCU (KB974558)?
3. Is there a way to make the Forward Compatibility Update, uhm.... *really work*?

---

**Edit**: *Related*:
[Unable to connect to TFS 2010 from VS2005 even though Forward Compat Update is installed.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3005822/unable-to-connect-to-tfs2010-from-vs2005-though-forward-compatibility-pack-is-ins)

Comment: Why don't you have the original installation media?

Comment: lost in the course of several moves.

Comment: Everything matches this: http://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2009/06/10/connecting-visual-studio-2008-team-explorer-to-team-foundation-server-2010/

Comment: @Hans - sort of; there's no discussion of the problem I'm having, and of course no solution either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question...

I was able to re-install VS2008 sp1, by providing an image of the [VS2008 90-day trial product](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=83c3a1ec-ed72-4a79-8961-25635db0192b&displaylang=en).  The installation of SP1 requested vs_setup.msi, and the 90-day trial ISO satisfied that requirement.

Once I did that, I was able to re-install the Forward Compatibility Update for TFS2010; at that point, I was able to connect to a TFS 2010 instance (Codeplex.com) from VS2008.

Also, to re-iterate, the installation order I used to get the Forward Compatibility Update to install, was the same as has been suggested elsewhere on this question, and also elsewhere on the internet:

1. VS2008
2. Team Explorer 2008
3. VS2008 SP1
4. Forward Compatibility Update.

In my case, VS2008 was *already* at SP1 level, and *already* had Team Explorer installed. No matter.  I re-installed Team Explorer, then SP1, then FCU.  I did not re-install the original VS2008 (because I don't have the original media!)

One note - the first time I tried this, it didn't work.  I installed each of #2, 3, and 4 *twice*, before VS2008 was able to connect correctly to TFS2010.

I hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 3):

I made this steps to check out what can break the install.

Installed:

1. Microsoft® Visual Studio® Team System 2008

   At this step I could use the original DVD or ISO image to repair the instalation or to Add/Remove features.
2. Microsoft® VS9 Service Pack 1

At this step I could not use the DVD or ISO image to repair or Add/Remove features. But I could still use the upgraded Setup files from $ VS9/Microsoft Visual Studio Team System 2008 Team Suite - ENU local subfolder.

I guess an upgraded DVD/ISO image of Microsoft® Visual Studio® Team System 2008 with SP1 may help to repair or Add/Remove features in no time.

Answer (score 0):

In order to connect from from VS 2008 to TFS 2010 you have to install the following software in  the same order:

1. Visual Studio 2008
2. Visual Studio Team System 2008 Team Explorer
3. Microsoft® Visual Studio® 2008 Service Pack 1
4. Visual Studio Team Explorer 2008 forward compatibility update to support TFS 2010

---

Try reinstalling VS2008 Forward Compatibility Update (KB974558)

Check these links:

http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=979258

http://codeplex.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Connect%20to%20TFS%20with%20Team%20Explorer%202008%20or%202005&referringTitle=Using%20TFS%20and%20Team%20Explorer%20with%20CodePlex

Wael

Comment: yes, thank you.  I read those blogs and I was trying to do that. My question centers on problems associated to that set of steps.  Problem #1: I don't have the original VS2008 install media.  Problem #2: when I install the FCU, it doesn't actually make any difference.